# "save image as" doesn't work in a window opened by javascript

Tags: javascript, image, save

This really bugs me as I can not see any reason for this behaviour.
On clicking on an image on a page it is presented in a new window/tab.
The right-click menu choice "save image as" is shown but clicking on it produces no discernable action.
If you then select "open image in new tab" that works and "save as..." works too.
Any ideas?
This is the javascript that creates the tab/window

```
popWindow=window.open("path","path");
popWindow.document.open();
popWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
popWindow.document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1"> ');
popWindow.document.write('<title>' + path + '</title>');
popWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
popWindow.document.write('<img src="file:///'+path+'"  width="900 height="675">');
popWindow.document.write("</body></html>");
popWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: Why are you opening a window and pointing to a URL of `"path"`? And, why are you using `file:///` in a web page?

Comment: The application displays all the image files in chrome's cache on the harddisk - the variable "path" is the path to the image file in the cache - it does not need to be present as the result is the same when window.open has no arguments. the addition of "file:///" was an attempt to mirror the code generated by chrome when opening the source in another tab - is does not need to be there and changes nothing.